# Web.config transforms add tree

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, webmatrix, web.config-transform

I want to add the following to the web config on release:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

There aren't any custom headers in the default web config so I get an error when I publish:  `No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders'`.

I can fix it my just adding the empty elements to the web.config like so:

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

However, it doesn't feel like the *correct* way.

Is there a more correct way to build the element tree on the transform?

Comment: Have tried removing xmlns= attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the empty `<customHeaders>` node to the web.config works because the transform you have is to insert the `<add .../>` node, not the `<customHeaders>` node.  It can only insert where it matches to that point.

To insert the tree of nodes, move the `xdt:Transform="Insert"` up a little in the XML.  If you start with a web.config of:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and transform it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You'll end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here's a helpful [web.config transformation tester](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/).